# Consequences for uninstalling the terminal

Tags: uninstall

Will uninstalling the program which allows me to use terminal also delete what I have installed using it?

Comment: Uninstalling the terminal application that was installed with Ubuntu is unwise for several reasons you may not expect. Do not do so unless you have the skills and understanding to repair your system from a recovery prompt. If you installed a different terminal application after installing Ubuntu, then you can probably safely remove it...as long as it is not the only terminal application. Read carefully and understand fully apt's list of proposed removals before proceeding.

Comment: No, that will not happen. However, you should probably not be uninstalling the terminal anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Even after you uninstall the terminal there are two relatively easy ways to access a command prompt, the virtual console (tty) and the root option in Recovery mode, so any program which requires access to a terminal (including root access) will still be accessible and run even if the terminal app is uninstalled. The same goes for all other apps installed in Ubuntu generally, because uninstalling the terminal only removes the terminal app itself and does not remove anything else.

Also the other packages aren't dependencies of the terminal. Uninstalling a package doesn't uninstall any other packages along with it except for packages that  depend on that package in order to function.

Answer (score 0):

No. It won't remove programs installed via terminal.

There is no reason to delete the terminal program. You could restrict user access though.

---

Update March 10 2019

#### Simulated removal

You can do a dry run and determine all other packages that are removed when `gnome-terminal` (the default terminal in most cases) is removed:

```
$ sudo apt remove -s --purge --auto-remove gnome-terminal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-terminal*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Purg gnome-terminal [3.18.3-1ubuntu1]
```

- `remove` tells you `apt` command you want to remove.
- `-s` is the "simulation" flag. No removals are done.
- `-purge` flag instructs to remove more than programs but user configuration files too.
- `--auto-remove` instructs to remove all packages that depend on `gnome-terminal`

In my case nothing depends on `gnome-terminal` and no extra programs will be removed. However the information below contradicts this.

#### Reverse Dependancies

To list all packages that do depend on `gnome-terminal` including the ones you don't have installed use:

```
$ apt-cache showpkg gnome-terminal
Package: gnome-terminal
Versions: 
3.18.3-1ubuntu1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: c385379e72ae70e0ca5a4dee09859951
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages
                  MD5: c385379e72ae70e0ca5a4dee09859951
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: c385379e72ae70e0ca5a4dee09859951


Reverse Depends: 
  gnome-core,gnome-terminal 3.14
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop,gnome-terminal
  gnome-panel,gnome-terminal
  ubuntu-desktop,gnome-terminal
  uicilibris,gnome-terminal
  ubuntukylin-desktop,gnome-terminal
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop,gnome-terminal
  sawfish,gnome-terminal
  pyragua,gnome-terminal
  nagstamon,gnome-terminal
  jwm,gnome-terminal
  hotssh,gnome-terminal 2.22.3
  gnome-panel,gnome-terminal
  byobu,gnome-terminal
  cinnamon-desktop-environment,gnome-terminal
  cinnamon,gnome-terminal
  gnome-terminal:i386,gnome-terminal
  ubuntu-desktop,gnome-terminal
  gnome-terminal-data,gnome-terminal
Dependencies: 
3.18.3-1ubuntu1 - gconf-service (0 (null)) libatk1.0-0 (2 1.12.4) libc6 (2 2.9) libcairo2 (2 1.2.4) libdconf1 (2 0.14.0) libgconf-2-4 (2 3.2.5) libglib2.0-0 (2 2.42.0) libgtk-3-0 (2 3.11.7) libnautilus-extension1a (2 1:2.91) libpango-1.0-0 (2 1.14.0) libuuid1 (2 2.16) libvte-2.91-0 (2 0.40.2) libx11-6 (0 (null)) dconf-gsettings-backend (16 (null)) gsettings-backend (0 (null)) python3 (0 (null)) python3-gi (0 (null)) gir1.2-glib-2.0 (0 (null)) gsettings-desktop-schemas (2 0.1.0) gnome-terminal-data (2 3.18) gnome-terminal-data (3 3.19) nautilus-open-terminal (0 (null)) yelp (0 (null)) gvfs (0 (null)) dbus-x11 (0 (null)) nautilus-open-terminal (0 (null)) gnome-terminal:i386 (32 (null)) 
Provides: 
3.18.3-1ubuntu1 - x-terminal-emulator:i386 (= ) gnome-terminal:i386 (= 3.18.3-1ubuntu1) x-terminal-emulator (= ) 
Reverse Provides: 
gnome-terminal:i386 3.18.3-1ubuntu1 (= 3.18.3-1ubuntu1)
```

The `Reverse Depends:` section is the one to focus on. If you have these packages installed they can be removed with `gnome-terminal` as well.

#### `ubuntu-desktop`

Let's focus on one of them `ubuntu-desktop` as mentioned in comments below and see what is available there:

```
$ apt search ubuntu-desktop
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
edubuntu-desktop/xenial 15.12.5 amd64
  educational desktop for Ubuntu

kubuntu-desktop/xenial 1.338 amd64
  Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system

lubuntu-desktop/xenial-updates 0.65.3 amd64
  Lubuntu Desktop environment

qtubuntu-desktop/xenial 0.62+16.04.20160322-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Qt plugins for Ubuntu Platform API (desktop)

ubuntu-desktop/xenial-updates,now 1.361.2 amd64 [installed]
  The Ubuntu desktop system

ubuntu-desktop-mir/xenial,xenial 0.4.3+16.04.20160323-0ubuntu1 all
  System compositor for Ubuntu Desktop

xubuntu-desktop/xenial 2.206 amd64
  Xubuntu desktop system
```

The list shows that `ubuntu-desktop/xenial-updates,now 1.361.2 amd64` is currently installed.

#### Optional tools

You can install:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-dev-tools
```

And then run:

```
$ reverse-depends gnome-terminal
Reverse-Recommends
==================
* cinnamon
* gnome-terminal-data
* pyragua
* ubuntu-desktop [amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el]
* ubuntu-desktop-minimal [amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el]
* ubuntu-unity-desktop [amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el]
* xinit

Reverse-Depends
===============
* cinnamon-desktop-environment
* gnome-core
* jwm
* nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
* sawfish
* vanilla-gnome-desktop [amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el]
* xorg

Packages without architectures listed are reverse-dependencies in: amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
```

This gives a more concise layout for reverse dependencies.

Comment: But it can delete `ubuntu-desktop` if it is `gnome-terminal` ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 I've updated answer with reverse dependencies but am at a loss why simulated `--auto-remove` doesn't list `ubuntu-desktop` for removal.